# How to reduce a nested collection without using mutable state?

Tags: clojure

Given a nested collection I would like to reduce it to only the k-v pairs which are the form [_ D] where D is an integer. For instance I would like to transform as follows:

```
; Start with this  ...
{:a {:val 1 :val 2} :b {:val 3 :c {:val 4}} :val 5}

; ... end with this
{:val 1, :val 2, :val 3, :val 4, :val 5}
```

I have written a function using postwalk as follows:

```
(defn mindwave-values [data]
  (let [values       (atom {})
        integer-walk (fn [x]
                       (if (map? x)
                         (doseq [[k v] x]
                           (if (integer? v) (swap! values assoc k v)))
                         x))]
    (postwalk integer-walk data)
    @values))
```

I am curious if it is possible to do this without using mutable state?

**EDIT** The original function was not quite correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example data structure is not a legal map, so I've changed it a bit:

```
(defn int-vals [x]
  (cond (map? x) (mapcat int-vals x)
        (coll? x) (when (= 2 (count x))
                    (if (integer? (second x))
                      [x]
                      (int-vals (second x))))))

user> (int-vals {:a {:x 1 :y 2} :b {:val 3 :c {:val 4}} :val 5})
([:y 2] [:x 1] [:val 4] [:val 3] [:val 5])
```

Your requirements are a bit vague: you say "collection", but your example contains only maps, so I've just had to guess at what you intended.

Comment: I like this. I updated my question at the same time you posted your answer - sorry about that. Your answer shows me how to do it without state though. Thank you.